# How to complete a addDog, removeDog, and toString method in this Kennel class?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I just wanted to receive some input on how to complete these methods in a kennel class I have to complete in Java.

It's probably simple for you all, but I'm currently not sure where I should start so any guidance is very welcome.

Here's the code:

```
public class APCS_5_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kennel myKennel = new Kennel();

        //myKennel.addDog(new Dog("dog1", 0);
        //myKennel.addDog(new Dog("dog2", 1);
        //myKennel.addDog(new Dog("dog3", 2);
        //myKennel.addDog(new Dog("dog4", 3);
        //myKennel.addDog(new Dog("dog5", 4);
        //System.out.println(myKennel);
        //myKennel.removeDog(2);
        //System.out.println(myKennel);
    }

}
```

/*
    The "Kennel cages" or array should always be filled from 0 moving positive`enter code here`.
    when a new dog is added to the Kennel it should go in the next available "cage" or index
    when a dog is removed it's spot must filled so if the dog in "cage 3" were removed
        that cage would need to be filled in with a dog from a higher numbered "cage" if there are any
    When the Kennel is printed it should display all filled cages only
*/

```
class Kennel {
    private Dog[] dogs;

    public Kennel() {
        dogs = new Dog[10];
    }

/*           complete addDog

    complete this method so that it adds the passed in Dog object to the next available "cage" represented by the next null array index in dogs
        In thinking through this you might need to add additional class level variables to properly facilitate this functionality
*/

    public void addDog(Dog d) {
    }

/*          complete removeDog
    complete this method so that the Dog with the id that is passed in is removed from the "Kennel"
    when a dog is removed it's spot must filled so if the dog in "cage 3" were removed
    that cage would need to be filled in with a dog from a higher numbered "cage" if there are any
*/

    public Dog removeDog(int id) {
        return new Dog("remove this and replace with the proper code" , -100);
    }


/*          complete toString

            for each "cage" should output as below for cage 1 or index 0 of the array

            cage:   1
                name:   dog1
                id:     0
*/

    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        return str;
    }
}


class Dog {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Dog(String n, int id) {
        name = n;
        this.id = id;
    }//constructor

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name\t"+name+"\nID:\t"+id;
    }

}//APCS_5_2
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I certainly would have liked you to post some code attempts , but since you mentioned you wanted guidance, see below a very quick attempt to recreate the addDog() .I didnt test much and this is unfinished but Please accept the answer if you like it and then I would like to work together to finish this up :)

```
class Kennel {

        private Dog[] dogs;
        private int availableCageIndex = 0;
        private int maxCageIndex=10;

    public Kennel() {
            dogs = new Dog[10];
        }

    public void addDog(Dog d) {
            if((availableCageIndex) ==maxCageIndex)
                return;//no space 
            dogs[availableCageIndex] = d;
            availableCageIndex++;
        }
```